# How can I compare the two special symbols with equality between @"＋" and @"+" in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield

Accepted a special symbol through UITextField, likes symbol ＋, I want to compare them with equality. @"＋" does not equal @"+". @"＋" by UITextField, @"+" by inputing on Xcode.But how can I compare them ? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Victor John did below answer help you out?

Comment: @user3182143 YES, the below answers helped me out

Comment: I have already chosen one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it by NSCharecterSet.

```
NSString *string = <your string>;

NSString *specialCharacterString = @"+＋";
NSCharacterSet *specialCharacterSet = [NSCharacterSet
                                       characterSetWithCharactersInString:specialCharacterString];

if ([string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:specialCharacterSet].length) {                
    NSLog(@"Success");
}
```

Comment: It works! `NSCharacterSet ` just for filtering. Once `*string` contains one of `*specialCharacterString` character and it returns `NSRange` `length` more than zero.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! @Bhadresh

Comment: But I used an another solution by myself. That is `[textField.text hasPrefix:@"＋"]` would be okay for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use case insensitive compare for both strings like

```
if( [@"+" caseInsensitiveCompare:@"＋"] == NSOrderedSame ) {
  // strings are equal except for possibly case
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work ! @Raj Aggrawal   It still returns false